# Perl: Parse json response for next curl request

Tags: perl

Is there a way in perl to parse json response for the next curl request?

e.g.

I have a command:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer DS_12345" -X GET https://api.xxx
```

The response is:

```
{
  "method":"a",
  "users":["user@xxx.com "],
  "status":"DONE",
  "export-url":"https://api.xxx/v1/export/DP_6789xxx"
}
```

When (Wait until) the response includes **"status":"DONE", instead of "FAIL" or "PROCESSING",** run the next step by taking response **"export-url":"https://api.xxx/v1/export/DP_6789xxx"** from the previous step. **When the status is "PROCESSING", I don't want to quit the program and run it again. Instead, I want to wait until the status is "DONE" and then go for the next step**

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer DS_12345" -X GET https://api.xxx/v1/export/DP_6789xxx?view=xml
```

I appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to use `curl`. Use [curl2lwp](https://corion.net/curl2lwp.psgi) to translate your requests to Perl using [LWP::UserAgent](http://p3rl.org/LWP::UserAgent).

Use a library to parse JSON. Here, I used [Cpanel::JSON::XS](http://p3rl.org/Cpanel::JSON::XS), but for simple stuff like this, any other should work as well.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent;
use Cpanel::JSON::XS;

my $ua = 'LWP::UserAgent'->new(send_te => 0);
my $req = 'HTTP::Request'->new(
    GET => 'https://api.xxx/',
    [
        'Accept'        => '*/*',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer DS_12345',
        'Host'          => 'api.xxx:443',
        'User-Agent'    => 'curl/7.55.1',
        'Content-Type'  => 'application/json',
    ],

);
my $res = $ua->request($req);
die $res->status_line unless $res->is_success;

my $response_structure = decode_json($res->decoded_content);
if ($response_structure eq 'DONE') {
    my $req = 'HTTP::Request'->new(
        GET => $response_structure->{'export-url'} . '?view=xml',
        [
            'Accept'        => '*/*',
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer DS_12345',
            'Host'          => 'api.xxx:443',
            'User-Agent'    => 'curl/7.55.1',
            'Content-Type'  => 'application/json',
        ],

    );
    my $res = $ua->request($req);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Would be nice to have a `curl2curl` command which produces Net::Curl code instead of LWP::UserAgent code!  (Net::Curl is way faster and supports parallel requests.)

Comment: @ikegami: Try bugging Corion for a while ;-)

Comment: Or I could write it myself, hehe

Comment: Aren't you missing a `->decoded_content` in `decode_json($res)`? Also, a `->is_success` before might be a reasonable idea.

Comment: thanks a lot @choroba. The status could be "processing", for which, I don't want to exit the program, instead I want to wait until it's finished (status: done) and then go to the next step.

Comment: @Emily: So wrap the first part of the code into a while loop.

Comment: @choroba thanks. can you be more specific? I don't know in perl how to wait for a step to finish before processing to the next

Comment: @Emily: Start a new question to ask a new question.