# Perl: how to wait for a curl step to finish before processing to the next

Tags: perl, curl

How does perl wait for a step before processing the next step?

e.g.

I have a command (checking status of the pervious data uploading step):

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer DS_12345" -X GET https://api.xxx
```

The response is:

```
{
  "method":"a",
  "users":["user@xxx.com "],
  "status":"DONE",
  "export-url":"https://api.xxx/v1/export/DP_6789xxx"
}
```

The status can be: "DONE", "FAIL" or "PROCESSING". When the status is "PROCESSING", I don't want to quit the program and run it again. Instead, I want to wait until the status is "DONE" and then go for the next step, by taking response "export-url":"https://api.xxx/v1/export/DP_6789xxx"from the previous step. (when it's "FAIL", report and exit)

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer DS_12345" -X GET https://api.xxx/v1/export/DP_6789xxx?view=xml
```

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: You did not share any Perl code... how are you invoking `curl`? If you are shelling out (via `system`, `open` or backticks), which it seems you are, you should consider instead using one of many existing CPAN modules like Net::Curl, or the venerable [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent).

Comment: @Possum: As already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60651266/1030675) ;-)

Comment: Aha, well then please ignore me...

Comment: Well, other people already warning you about some issues in your post. So I'll just to recommend you to consider to use `WWW::Mechanize` module. But, If you really need to use Curl, you can find many "flavors" on CPAN - https://metacpan.org/search?q=curl

Choose your destiny!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a while loop:

```
my $result = 'PROCESSING';
while ($result eq 'PROCESSING') {
    my $response = ... # 
    $result = $response->{status};
    sleep 5;
}
```

Comment: thanks @choroba If I understood correctly, the $response here is $response_structure in your previous program? And this ...# means the part starts from "my $response_structure = decode_json($res->decoded_content);...."?